My load delay and load time are bad in LCP report, What should i do?
This is my report from PageSpeed Insights
https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-ttbeb-com/z14r7yl4wt?form_factor=mobile
I want to reach score of 90+ for both desktop and mobile, so i need to improve load delay and load time for both devices.
I decreased the image size and make it webp, but there wasn't any improvement
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The PageSpeed Insights report you shared includes some interesting info about your LCP element and how the time was spent rendering it:

Any time the delay phases are substantially longer than 0 ms, that's a sign that the page is doing something inefficient. Here in the desktop assessment, your load delay is 1,430 ms. That's a long time, especially considering that the budget for a "good" LCP is 2,500 ms.
I looked at the way this image is included in the initial HTML and I noticed that it's doing a strange anti-pattern to lazily load the image source. Here's the simplified markup:
<img
  fetchpriority="high"
  width="1491"
  height="1333"
  alt=""
  sizes="(max-width: 1491px) 100vw, 1491px"
  nitro-lazy-srcset="..."
  nitro-lazy-src="..."
  class="kb-img wp-image-752 nitro-lazy"
  decoding="async"
  nitro-lazy-empty
  id="Nzk6NzUz-1"
  src="data:image/svg+xml;nitro-empty-id=Nzk6NzUz-1;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTQ5MSAxMzMzIiB3aWR0aD0iMTQ5MSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMzMzIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPjwvc3ZnPg=="
/>

The src attribute is set to a data URI of a transparent SVG. The actual image source(s) are included in the nitro-lazy-src and nitro-lazy-srcset attributes. These attributes are signatures of the NitroPack plugin.
So what seems to be happening is that your plugin is altering the way the image is marked up in HTML so that it's transparent until the plugin's JavaScript has a chance to execute and lazily swap in the correct src attribute.
This is NOT good for performance. In fact, we on the Chrome team have an article documenting this exact anti-pattern in our recommendation to ensure that the LCP resource is discoverable from the HTML source.
It also undermines the benefit of the fetchpriority="high" attribute, which would have started loading the image source as early as possible. However, since the image source is an inline transparent SVG, the browser doesn't know the actual image source early enough for the optimization to help.
For context, Chrome used to consider the time that the transparent SVG rendered (not the actual image) to be the page's LCP time. However, this was a bug because real users can't actually see the SVG, and to them it'd feel like the page loaded noticeably later. So since Chrome 112, low-entropy images like this have been ignored as LCP candidates. It's possible you're using an older version of the plugin that implements this outdated antipattern, so it's worth seeing if you can upgrade.
Hopefully by removing the lazy loading behavior, your LCP image can start loading sooner and you'll be closer to the 2,500 ms mark.

Thanks, I disabled the nitro pack plugin, the time improved but it is still high, any suggests?
